# Dot Net Nuke: How to add DNN's Captcha Control in .cshtml (Razor Host Module)

Tags: dotnetnuke

Is there a way to add DNN's Captcha Control in a .cshtml file (Razor Host Module)?

I found a variety of examples in ascx files, but not a single one using .cshtml.

ASCX example: http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2008/01/27/implementing-captcha-in-a-dotnetnuke-module.aspx

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the same [blog post you shared above](http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2008/01/27/implementing-captcha-in-a-dotnetnuke-module.aspx), there is a [comment](http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2008/01/27/implementing-captcha-in-a-dotnetnuke-module.aspx#comment-2854722179) by the author that suggests that you cannot use the DNN Captcha control in an MVC/SPA/WebAPI context, as it is a deprecated Telerik WebForms based control.

Since you are using Razor, I'm assuming you are developing an SPA/WebAPI module.

Have you considered using [Google's ReCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/invisible.html) instead, as Mitchell Sellers suggested in [his comment](http://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2008/01/27/implementing-captcha-in-a-dotnetnuke-module.aspx#comment-2854722179)?